# sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to reimann integrable funtion

Tags: integration, sequence-of-function

$$a,b\in \mathbb{R}.\, \, f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\textrm{ is bounded. } f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\textrm{ is reimann integrable .}\\ \textrm{Prove that }\exists \left \{ f_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty }\textrm{ such that }f_{n}:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\textrm{ is continuous }\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \textrm{ such that }\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_{n}(x)=f(x)\: \: \forall x\in [a,b]$$
I know this is true when f is continuous. What about when f has at most countable number of discontinuities

Comment: Do you about Lebesgue integration and measure theory? You can easily get an answer from there. Otherwise, I'm not sure it's possible. It's hard (/impossible) to even characterize the Riemann integrable functions with measure theory (as far as I know).

Comment: @KeeferRowan I'm not an analyst, but can't you just convolve with bump functions tending to the delta function?

Comment: If $a$ is a point of discontinuity then $f_n(a)\to f(a)$ won't be true. So you need to specify what convergence you'll have. A function that is continuous a.e. is Lebesgue integrable and you can find $f_n$ converging in the 1-norm.

Comment: @Chrystomath pointwise convergence